# Selecting the maximum count from a GROUP BY operation

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, max

Forgive my SQL knowledge, but I have a `Person` table with following data -

```
Id          Name
----        ------
1           a
2           b
3           b
4           c
```

and I want the following result -

```
Name      Total
------    ------
b         2
```

If I use the `GROUP BY` query -

```
SELECT Name, Total=COUNT(*) FROM Person GROUP BY Name
```

It gives me -

```
Name   Total
------ ------
a      1
b      2
c      1
```

But I want only the one with maximum count. How do I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want ties

```
SELECT top (1) with ties Name, COUNT(*) AS [count]
  FROM Person 
 GROUP BY Name  
 ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: @NerotheZero If there are multiple entries which have all the same maximum, then `with ties` means that all of these entries will be displayed, and not just one. *(in olympic games, "ties" means that two or more runners had the same top speed, so they all share the gold medal)*

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this in SQL Server would be to use the `top` syntax:

```
SELECT   TOP 1 Name, COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM     Person 
GROUP BY Name  
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Didn't quite get that. Where did you get that `2` in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: 2nd item in the select

Comment: The `order by` clause can receive ordinals in your `select` list. `2` is the second column - i.e., `count(*)`.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
WITH MaxGroup AS (
   SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS Total
   FROM Person
   GROUP BY Name)
SELECT Name, Total
FROM MaxGroup
WHERE Total = (SELECT MAX(Total) FROM MaxGroup)
```

Comment: Well, that works, but it is too cumbersome. There are more elegant and simple solutions. Like `SELECT TOP 1`.... Does it ring ? *(No vote. SQLPolice never downvotes)*

Comment: @SQLPolice: `SELECT TOP 1`, without `tie`, might not always be a good idea. Just an opinion, based on my scenario ;)

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) 
        FROM Person 
        GROUP BY Name 
        having COUNT(*)=( SELECT max(COUNT(*)) FROM Person GROUP BY Name) ;
```

Comment: Subquery is too cumbersome. It's much simpler with a `SELECT TOP 1 ...`

Comment: Sorry pal - `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery` :(

Comment: @SQLPolice yaa my query is cumbersome i noticed it. but i have a doubt is there any performance improvement in above upvoted Query?? Does those upvoted Query return redundant max values like for example (a,4) (b,4) if both a and b are max values..

Answer (score 0):

The above answer of [@Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik) is very straightforward to understand. But for me, I tried this SQL subquery method & it works for me!

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Total)
FROM (SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS Total 
      FROM Person 
      GROUP BY Name);
```

Basically, I grouped the table data by the names from where I queried the max count from that intermediate table!